# Tomcat godaddy ssl certificate private keys error

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate

I have purchased an ssl certificate from godaddy and am having some trouble configuring it to run with Tomcat. In particular I get the following error message :

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
```

Godaddy gives 3 files for the certificate, and I have attempted to add these to the keystore as follows :

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gdig2.crt.pem
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file <random hex string>.crt
```

which I found here : http://www.calamitycoder.com/WebSiteNotes/goDaddySHA2SSL.php

I have configured Tomcat's server.xml as :

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
   keystoreFile="${user.home}/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="password"
   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS">
```

`

The Tomcat version is 8.5.20.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Not sure if this is the Tomcat version as I have not found much regarding this error after many hours of searching.
Thanks !

Update :

I deleted the current keys :

```
sudo keytool -delete -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore
sudo keytool -delete -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore
sudo keytool -delete -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

and added the keys as recommended in the comments :

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -file <random hex string>.crt
```

but unfortunately find the same error :

```
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:258)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineSetKeyEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineSetKeyEntry(KeyStoreDelegator.java:117)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineSetKeyEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:226)
```

I will continue to play around with this, any additional ideas are most welcome. Thank you !

Comment: You must omitt `-trustcacerts` when importing the signed certificate (hex name), and use the same alias you used when generating the keypair and CSR. Don't import the PEM file.

Comment: I would recommend go to Godaddy official web site and follow its instructions of how get imported the certificates and also how properly create your keystore: https://ca.godaddy.com/help/tomcat-generate-csrs-and-install-certificates-5239

Comment: And *not* follow arbitrary Internet junk. The official sites are there for a reason.  NB Your link not found.

Comment: Actually I was led to look for random internet sites since the Godaddy site is inaccurate. It makes no mention of correct file names, or which file is 'root', 'intermediate' etc.
The link works ok for me ? Thank you for your suggestions, I will give them a try and report back -

Answer (score 0):

Additional Research:

Godaddy Cert

CentOS 7.3.1611

Only Change - Tomcat 8.5.20 upgraded from 8.5.3

conf/server.xml

```
Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="secret"
       clientAuth="false" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
       sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
```

Works in Tomcat 8.5.3 But in 8.5.20

```
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to direct using of certificate files. And also add key file to the configuration.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/*.key"
                     certificateFile="conf/<random hex string>.crt"
                     certificateChainFile="conf/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 8.5.20 I had the same error message with my certificates and I had to explicitly set the alias with

```
<Connector keyAlias="tomcat" .... >
```

in the connector. Before I added the alias Tomcat tried to use the included CA certificate and failed.